# Jenkins concurrent builds stuck due to one another

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job that is set to run concurrent builds. The concurrent builds start correctly, but if there are more than one builds running, other builds don't complete even though their work is done.

I am using **Flexible Publish Plugin** as **Post Build Action** and it never seems to start. 
I am not using **email-ext** plugin which is known to have this issue.

Comment: Do you have any build output that indicates what step the builds are stuck on ?

Comment: Does it eventually finish? Probably in a sequential order? AFAIK the checkpoints issue is not dedicated to __email-ext__ plugin solely.